# Flutter Drawer lazy load when extracted to custom widget

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a drawer on my main page which became bloated with content and logic. For example, I need to fetch an image, get some data from Internet and so on. After extracting Drawer in new `MyCustomDrawerWidget` which extends `StatefulWidget`, its state has `build` function which looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Drawer(
    child: ...
  );
}
```

My `HomePageState` has `build` function which looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Home page'),
    ),
    drawer: MyCustomDrawerWidget(),
    body: ...
  );
}
```

After refactoring the code like this, I noticed how drawer does not get initialized when page loads. It would initialize just after I open the drawer, which is bad because user needs to wait for data to be loaded.

Is there a way to set eager loading on drawer to get initialized along with the page?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The `Scaffold` only attaches the drawer when necessary.

The solution: Move the data loading logic into the parent widget. You can still encapsulate it in a separate model class (e.g. `DrawerModel`), but this class must be instantiated when the parent widget is initialized. Keep it in the `State` of the parent. Pass `DrawerModel` to your drawer widget.

You have to be a bit careful when using streams and futures, because those usually can not be resubscribed. I would recommend you to use a `StreamBuilder` in the drawer widget that is connected to a `BehaviorSubject` in your `DrawerModel`.

That's very much the BLoC pattern. Do you need a code example?

Answer (score 1):

Problem with having **Drawer in MainPage**:

- Content, more logic, fetch an image, get some data from the Internet and so on.

Problem with having **Drawer in MyCustomDrawerWidget**:

- Loading time, bad user experience

I would *suggest* getting the `hybrid` approach to solve the problem.

- Trigger the network calls in *MainPage*
- Send `future` to the `MyCustomDrawerWidget` (If the user opens drawer before network call completes, we can show loader based on future value)
- Move the logic and contents related to drawer into MyCustomDrawerWidget.

  ```
  class MyCustomDrawerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    var _future;

    MyCustomDrawerWidget(this._future);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Drawer(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              var data = snapshot.data;
              return new Text(data);
            } else {
              return new Text("loading");
            }
          },
          future: _future,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ```

And in **MainPage**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  val future = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () => "new value") //network call
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home page'),
      ),
      drawer: MyCustomDrawerWidget(future),
      body: ...
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.